# Open bootstrap modal with Js ( not working )

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am curently building a website and I need to open a modal automaticaly when I go to a page, here is the code:

http://pastebin.com/bhSL82j8

It isnt working.

EDIT : http://pastebin.com/mGtR1VK1

It isnt working anyway

Comment: Don't link to the code, include it in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open your modal when the page is loaded. Use something like this to make it happen:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#modal').modal();
});
```